# Xamarin studio -- set search to default to case insensitive?

Tags: xamarin-studio

Whenever I put a capital letter into the search box, Xamarin Studio decides the search should be case sensitive.  If my prior search was case insensitive, I'd like it to remain case insensitive, even if I put a capital letter into the search box.  Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the down arrow next to the big magnifying glass gives you an option to change case sensitivity.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the next one will become case sensitive again.

Comment: Which version are you on? My 4.2.3 looks ok.

Comment: 4.2.2.  It says there are no updates available in the stable channel.